# Terraform destroy not working for DB instances in AWS

Tags: database, terraform, devops, terraform-provider-aws

I used `terraform destroy`. Then I got this msg and the DB instances are still there.

*Error* : **DB Instance Final Snapshot Identifier is required when a final snapshot is required.**

Do I need to create a snapshot.
If so is it possible to do it directly in the console ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is also valid to manually delete the RDS. Terraform will pickup the change.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `skip_final_snapshot` argument to evade this behavior, which is what you implied you are seeking here: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/db_instance#skip_final_snapshot.

Add that argument with a `true` value to your `aws_db_instance`, `apply` the new config to update the DB instance, and then you can freely destroy without the error requiring the final snapshot.